# Add two consecutive values in a column with sql select

Tags: mysql, select

[image: Tables]

If I have 'Table_A' like above, is it possible to generate Table_B from it by using select sql only? I would like to keep the column 'pc2' and create the column 'pc4' to sum the values of 'pc3' and the value of 'pc1' from the consecutive row.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`LEAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) window function to get the next value of `pc1` of each row:

```
SELECT day, 
       pc2,
       pc3 + LEAD(pc1, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY day) AS pc4
FROM Table_A;
```

If you want to create a new table `Table_B`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_B AS
SELECT day, 
       pc2,
       pc3 + LEAD(pc1, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY day) AS pc4
FROM Table_A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following SQL

```
SELECT a.day,a.pc1,(a.pc3+b.pc2) AS pc4
FROM TABLE_A AS a. TABLE_A AS b
WHERE a.day=(b.day+1)
ORDER BY a.day
```

Comment: This does not work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vMVF7GYa4BjWYA3i9bEng4/0

Comment: Yes there was a mistake try the following   SELECT a.day,a.pc2,(a.pc3+b.pc1) AS pc4
FROM TABLE_A AS a, TABLE_A AS b
WHERE b.day=(a.day+1)
ORDER BY a.day

Comment: Still, does not work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vMVF7GYa4BjWYA3i9bEng4/1

Comment: It is working as per your requirement TABLE_B **Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

    create table TABLE_A(day int, pc1 int, pc2 int, pc3 int);
    
    insert into TABLE_A values
    (1, 1, 3, 5), 
    (2, 2, 6, 4), 
    (3, 5, 2, 1), 
    (4, 3, 9, 2);

---

**Query #1**

    SELECT a.day,a.pc2,(a.pc3+b.pc1) AS pc4 
    FROM TABLE_A AS a, TABLE_A AS b 
    WHERE b.day=(a.day+1) ORDER BY a.day;

| day | pc2 | pc4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 3   | 7   |
| 2   | 6   | 9   |
| 3   | 2   | 4   |

---

www.db-fiddle.com/f/vMVF7GYa4BjWYA3i9bEng4/1

Comment: Where is the last row with day=4?

Comment: This should work    SELECT a.day,a.pc2,(a.pc3+COALESCE(b.pc1,0)) AS pc4
FROM TABLE_A AS a LEFT JOIN TABLE_A AS b
ON (b.day=(a.day+1))
ORDER BY a.day

Comment: It seems to be working but as I use temporary table I get the error 1137 - 'can't reopen table'.

Comment: To Over come this error Try the following.... "WITH CTE AS (SELECT * FROM TABLE_A)
SELECT a.day,a.pc2,(a.pc3+COALESCE(b.pc1,0)) AS pc4 FROM TABLE_A AS a LEFT JOIN CTE AS b ON (b.day=(a.day+1)) ORDER BY a.day"

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that too, but still got an error: "Syntax error: WITH is not valid input at this position"

Comment: This is because you are using MySql version less than 8.0. If it is so then you have to create a separate table.